# modal not appearing automatically when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I could not find the reason why my modal does not trigger when this page loads.

My modal has the div tag `id="my-modal"` and should work when I use the same ID in `$('#my-modal').modal('show');` but nothing appears.

Both alternatives (using `$(document).ready(function(){` or `$(window).on('load',function(){`) have no effect in the page.

Can anyone help? Here is the code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('info.vc.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>COUPONS | CARDS</title>
    <meta name="author" content="STASHTECH">
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />

    <link href="../_lib/v/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="../_lib/v/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../cards/css/style.css">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../img/favicon.png">
    <link rel="icon" href="../img/favicon.png">

    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body class="bg-color-white">

    <?php require_once('header-only.php'); ?>

      <div id="my-modal" class="modal text-align-center">
        <div class="m-content">
          <div class="m-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h1>THANK YOU FOR CLAIMING A COUPON!</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="m-body">
            <h1 class="bold_font color-mwc-orange">YOU HAVE CHOSEN:</h1>
              <br>

              <?php
                $claim_coupon = $rowProduct['title'];
                $claim_coupon = strtoupper($claim_coupon);
                echo '<h1 class="bold_font color-mwc-blue">'.$claim_coupon.'</h1>';
              ?>

              <br>
              <div id="container">
                <?php
                    if ($packageid <= 1) {
                    $ribbon = 'ribbon-elite';
                  } else if ($packageid == 2) {
                    $ribbon = 'ribbon-premium';
                  } else if ($packageid == 3) {
                    $ribbon = 'ribbon-luxury';
                  }

                  echo('<a href="membership.php"><img style="display:inline;" src="../img/'.$ribbon.'.png"></a> ');

                    if($packageid == 1) {
                    echo('<h1 style="display:inline;">Elite <br/></h1>');
                  } else if($packageid == 2) {
                    echo('<h1 style="display:inline;">Premium <br/></h1>');
                  } else if($packageid == 3) {
                    echo('<h1 style="display:inline;">Luxury <br/></h1>');
                  }
                ?>
              </div>
            <h3>to view other coupons you have claimed, <a href="membership.php" class="no-underline">click here.</a></h3>
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 spacer"></div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img src="../img/uploads/<?php echo($rowProduct['photosrc']); ?>" class="img-responsive clinic">
          <img src="../img/shadow-bottom.png" class="img-responsive">


          <div class="col-md-12 spacer"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-align-center">
            <input type="submit" class="full_width registerbtn " id="back" value="BACK">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 border-top spacer"><br></div>


          <div class="col-md-12 spacer"><br></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 border-left">
          <br>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <br>
            <br>

            <?php  echo($rowProduct['body']); ?>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div> 

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 spacer">
        </div>
      </div>


<div class="row border-top">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <br> RELATED CARDS <br><br>

    <?php
      $i = 0;
      foreach($lstProduct as $rowProduct) {
    ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 spacer">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <?php
            $packageid = $rowProduct['packageid'];

            if ($packageid <= 1)
              $ribbon = 'ribbon-elite';
            elseif ($packageid == 2)
              $ribbon = 'ribbon-premium';
            elseif ($packageid == 3)
              $ribbon = 'ribbon-luxury';

            for($j = 0; $j < $packageid; $j++) {
              echo(' <img src="../img/'.$ribbon.'.png" class="small-icon"> ');
            }
          ?>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-12">
          <a href="info.php?i=<?php echo($rowProduct['productid']) ?>">
            <img src="../img/uploads/<?php echo($rowProduct['photosrc']) ?>" class="img-responsive clinic">
            <img src="../img/shadow-bottom.png" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php
      $i = $i + 1;
      if($i >= 3) {
        echo('<div class="col-md-12"></div>');
        $i = 0;
      }
    } ?>

  </div>
</div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 spacer">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-modal').modal('show');
    });
    </script>
    <script src="js/back_button.js"></script>
    <script src="../_lib/v/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../_lib/v/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../_lib/v/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../_lib/v/jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output for us to be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: done as you said, separated the modal and the javascript

Comment: No, that's not what he meant. In fact, separating the code into those pieces removes context and makes it harder to understand. The original was easier to work out. All you've done with your edit is pointlessly duplicate some of the existing content, but out of its context. Instead what we're after is debugging data - e.g. have you tried to check for errors in your console, or step through the code in the JS debugger to see what happens? You need to investigate properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although we don't have any error or debugging data provided in the question, if I had to just make an assumption from looking at the code, I'd say the most likely issue is that you're trying to run jQuery code before you've loaded jQuery into the page. This is likely to be generating an error in your Console such as `$ is not defined` - this is telling you that it cannot find the necessary jQuery functions to be able execute your code.

Browsers execute `<script>` blocks as soon as they load them - and the blocks are loaded in the order they are found in the HTML.

Try moving

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-modal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

below all the other `<script>` blocks - as a general rule you should normally load external JS before on-page JS to avoid this kind of dependency issue.

Comment: surprisingly this is the issue of my problem, thanks for the clarification. thats why im surprised by what you said to show the errors because there are none to begin with.

Comment: @testingmode No problem, glad it resolves your problem. I'm surprised you didn't see any errors though. This demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8ecukamf/ shows you the same kind of problem, if you look in the browser's Console. And this demo: shows it fixed using the method I described: http://jsfiddle.net/8ecukamf/1/

Comment: @testingmode Anyway if the answer has helped you, please don't forget to mark it as "accepted" (click on the tick next to the answer so it turns green) and/or give an upvote. This is both helpful as an indicator to future readers that it's a useful answer, and also encourages others to answer you future questions (because they can see in your [history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10921815/testingmode) that you give prompt feedback (which of course generates reputation points for the answerers). Thanks :-)